How do use template literals in SASS / SCSS?
I'm stuck writing a SCSS mixin like so:
@mixin icon($unicode) {
    content: $unicode;
}

I'm trying to get the content to feature a backslash in front of it so I can use the mixin like so: @include mixins.icon(f123) and it return content: "\f123".
How can I use template literals in SCSS? VS Code's formatter keeps removing backslashes.
